# How to manually install Flask extensions?

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask project which I've put the flask module (version 0.9) directly beside my app.py file. I've done this so that I can bundle everything into a version control repository that won't require anyone else using it to install additional Python modules.

I want to use [flask-login](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Login/) so I've tried to manually install it by downloading the latest version and putting the flask_login.py file in my "local" flask/ext/ directory. However, while I can `import flask` and `import flask.ext`, I am unable to `import flask.ext.login` with Python throwing `ImportError: No module named flask.ext.login`. `import flask.ext.flask_login` throws an import error as well.

Is there something I have to do differently if Flask and it's extensions are local to the app.py?

Comment: I updated my question. I can `import flask` and `import flask.ext`

Comment: ``ImportError: No module named flask.ext.flask`` not ``flask.ext.login`` ! Where do you have ``import flask.ext.flask`` ?

Comment: @mouad that was a mistake in transcribing the error. I've corrected my question to reflect the _actual_ error I received.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. I know this isn't the typical way of dealing with Flask extensions, but it isn't wrong when dealing with python modules. I've made it clear in the question title that this isn't the normal approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to put the `flask_login.py` file in the same directory as my app.py file. No modification of the `flask/ext/__init__.py` file is necessary.

The `flask.ext` module is intended only as a an extension importer, *not* a repository for installed extensions. Based on the import path, I thought the `flask/ext` folder was where extensions were to be copied. This was incorrect. Extensions simply need to be somewhere on the python path.

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn't throw the exception in your case, this Flask module is responsible for modifying the standard `import` hook in the `ext` folder:
https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/exthook.py

So, I don't think putting `flask_login.py` into `flask/ext` is the right way to use extensions in Flask. The documentation recommends to use `pip install flask-login` or `python setup.py install`. After that you can do:

```
import flask_login
```

If you still want to do it manually, remove the `setup()` call from [ext/__ init__.py](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/ext/__init__.py).
It probably has a good reason why the Flask guys did it this way though :-)

Comment: Right, but the point was to manually install everything so it could be self-contained in a version control repository that won't require additional installs. I've looked at the setup.py file but can't determine how it achieves the installation.

Comment: Modifying the flask source seems drastic, but even that didn't work. I still get a `ImportError: No module named login`

Comment: `import flask.ext.flask_login`?

Comment: I mentioned in @arturhoo's deleted answer that `import flask.ext.flask_login` also fails with an `ImportError`. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: So it even fails with the modified __ init __.py?

Comment: Ah, no it works with a blank `__init__.py` file. I must have been still trying to import `flask.ext.login` rather than `flask.ext.flask_login` the last time I tried.

Comment: I've submitted this as an issue to the Flask github bug tracker: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/621

Answer (score 1):

> Right, but the point was to manually install everything so it could be self-contained in a version control repository that won't require additional installs. I've looked at the setup.py file but can't determine how it achieves the installation. – Soviut Oct 25 at 10:06

Why not use virtualenv to achieve this? You can push your env to source control as well, although that's not normal usage.

See: http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/

Comment: I don't want the students using this repository to have to contend with any extra layers like virtualenv as it will be a distraction from their primary task.

Comment: Also, it has been mentioned that certain hosts like Google App Engine don't allow virtual environments so putting the modules side by side is the only solution.