# ImportError: No module named flask.ext.login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have a problem with flask_login module.

i have installed flask_login module successfully. Also from the command prompt i can run this script easily with no error:

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 07:43:08) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from flask.ext.login import LoginManager
```

But when I am running this script:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World! Welcome"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

i am getting the error :

```
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.login
```

What is the mistake i am doing. I am very new to this flask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you running the script? How was `flask_login` installed?

Comment: Random guesses: Wrong Python interpreter? Virtualenv?

Comment: I am not using Virtualenv , I have installed flask separately with all the dependency modules.Actually I am just testing if the set up is fine or not. I tried via virtualenv but i am getting some error. So tried to installed everything separately. The piece of code works fine until I have added `from flask.ext.login import LoginManager`.

Comment: I installed flask_login from `https://pypi.python.org/` site

Comment: You are right @Martijn Pieters  asking `How are you running the script?`

Comment: Your question was asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065682/how-to-manually-install-flask-extensions/13077029#13077029

Answer (score 43):

If following does not work:

```
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager
```

try the following:

```
from flask_login import LoginManager
```

This is the new convention.

To find the flask-login version, you can run the following command in terminal. Just change the name to know the version of other packages.

```
pip show flask-login
```

Comment: I had this problem with Flask-session. Direct from the docs - `from flask.ext.session import Session`. This solution solved that problem too. `from flask_session import Session`

Comment: I had the same thing with `from flask.ext.scss import Scss` and used `from flask_scss import Scss` instead and it solved it. I'm using Pythonista on iPad.

Answer (score 14):

Install pip and then use the following command:

`C:\Python27\scripts>pip install Flask-Login`

Answer (score 10):

If you have already installed flask-login by

```
$pip install flask_login
```

Try replacing the

```
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager
```

with

```
from flask_login import LoginManager
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an environment error -- whatever IDE you're using doesn't have the PYTHONPATH set properly. You can test this out by creating a small test file: test.py, with the following contents:

```
from os import environ
print environ.get('PYTHONPATH')
```

If the PYTHONPATH doesn't contain the directory that holds your Flask-Login package, then that's the issue.

Comment: where should we create this script ?

Comment: PYTHONPATH is empty in virtualenv, so that doesn't seem likely.

Answer (score 1):

Initially I installed flask_login on virtual environment. I found out that its trying to find on the machine. So I installed it globally as;

**mycomp#** *pip install -U flask_login*

That solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

See For me the simple solution is to just remove .ext from `flask.ext.login` and instead just type `flask_login`. This works for python 3 and make sure that you have correctly installed your desired package.

Answer (score 0):

Strange But it worked when I tried to run the script from Command prompt

```
C:\Users\dib\Desktop>python foo.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Feb/2014 18:03:52] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

But when I am trying to run from the python default IDE `pressing f5` it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The solution  is simple. Different versions of the flask run with different codes so just change the code : flask.ext.login to the code: flask_login

It should run smoothly.

Note that this also applies to bootstrap. Actually inorder to find the solution I had the error while importing bootstrap.