# Importing error : flask_login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am using flask for backend development where i need to manage user accounts.
I choose flask-login pip package for it.
I installed this by,

```
pip install flask-login
```

And imported it in code by,

```
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_required, login_user, logout_user
```

It resulting in,

```
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.login
```

How to tackle this?

Comment: Where have you found that `from flask.ext.login`? I can see `from flask_login` only in the [documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest)

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701174/importerror-no-module-named-flask-ext-login

Comment: @yeputons , i checked this https://github.com/shekhargulati/flask-login-example/blob/master/flask-login-example.py

Comment: @galeej tried that too

Comment: @ajinkygadewar That's code from 2013, looks like API has been changed since then, hence the error. I'd recommend adding details about your attempts in the question instead of simply stating that you've tried it unsuccessfully.

Comment: @yeputons , i mentioned in question what i tried

Answer (score 1):

Also, just try

```
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_required, login_user, logout_user
```

Comment: still same issue

Comment: @ajinkygadewar It cannot be the same issue: at least the error message should now say something about `flask_login`, not `flask.ext.login`.

Comment: @yeputons , i meant the issue is same , ` ImportError: No module named flask.ext.login `